# It is possible to determine with what gcc vesion a library(.so) has been compiled?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a 3rd party library : lib3rdPartylib.so.It is possible to check with what version of gcc has been this library compiled?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the GCC version used to compile a given ELF executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387040/how-to-retrieve-the-gcc-version-used-to-compile-a-given-elf-executable)

Comment: By running the  " readelf -Wa lib3rdPartylib.so | grep 'GCC[[:alnum:]_.]*' --only-match | sort | uniq | tail "
I can see GCC_3.0.
Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try objdump to see comment section:

```
objdump -s -j .comment lib3rdPartylib.so
```