# How to identify whether two different versions of gcc are compatible?

Tags: c, gcc

Sometimes I get libraries from different design teams. One uses gcc 3.x and another uses gcc 4.x. How can I identify whether these two libraries are compatible? I know it is something with libstdc++, but could you please give me a clear answer?

Comment: Adding C tag for more visibility and it is relevant even in C programming

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387040/how-to-retrieve-the-gcc-version-used-to-compile-a-given-elf-executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good starting point

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compatibility.html

This article discusses binary compatibility ( it can apply to libraries too ) between different tools. This still holds good when the different tools are differnt versions of gcc. One major thing to be checked is application binary interface (ABI) conformance.

And this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801938/gcc-abi-compatibility) says that since GCC 3.4.0 ABI is forward compatible. I.E. a library made using an older release can be linked with a newer one and it should work .

Answer (score 0):

this command may make a little help:

> strings - YourProgram  | grep GCC