# Extracting gcc version information from static library

Tags: gcc, version, static-libraries

Assume that you have a static library built with gcc by another person and you want to find out the version number of gcc that was used for compiling. Is there an easy way to extract this information from the library file?

I already tried out readelf, but all the switches I've used so far did not lead to a gcc version number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the GCC version used to compile a given ELF executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387040/how-to-retrieve-the-gcc-version-used-to-compile-a-given-elf-executable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @dbrank0 I could retrieve the gcc version information from the static library. The solution that helped is provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9673793/3868995
While `readelf -wi <library>` only lists the included files of the library, `strings -a <library> |grep "GCC: ("` made the job in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This gets recorded in DW_AT_producer attribute in DWARF debug info. So if you have debug info, try this:

> ```
> objdump -Wi yourlibrary.a|grep "DW_AT_producer"
> ```

I didn't see any official documentation for this attribute, so you might have to check...

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. When I execute `objdump -Wi` I only get a list of all object files within the static library and the regarding file formats (_file format elf64-x86-64_).

Comment: Then probably does not contains this (or any) debug information. This is useless then.

Comment: btw: this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387040/how-to-retrieve-the-gcc-version-used-to-compile-a-given-elf-executable/2393297#2393297

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find this thread while searching on stackoverflow.