# How to detect code compiled with LTO?

Tags: gcc, lto

Exist any way to detect if code is compiled with -flto?

Example is classic library or executable under Linux compiled with GCC (4.9.1), without debugging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Considering that LTO information is stored in several ELF sections inside object files (see [LTO file sections](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-object-file-layout.html)), you could try and see what [`readelf`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/readelf.html) returns (as used for instance in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2387121/6309)).

Look for `.gnu.lto_.xxx` entries.

Comment: For clang, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048414/clang-how-to-check-if-lto-was-performed?noredirect=1&lq=1