# Clang: How to check if LTO was performed

Tags: clang, llvm, link-time-optimization

For gcc, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322946/how-to-detect-code-compiled-with-lto) tells us how we can verify that Link-Time Optimization was performed. For clang, I cannot see any entries similar to `.gnu.lto`.

More specifically, I have a binary where I am quite sure that LTO should have a significant benefit, but I am seeing nothing. I wonder if cmake actually does the right thing.

**Is there any way to tell if clang performed LTO by looking at a binary or an *.o file?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option would be to try running `llvm-dis` on one of your .o files. If the LTO was actually performed, the .o files contain llvm bitcode and `llvm-dis` will produce the .ll file containing humain-readable llvm ir. Otherwise it will produce the error message "error: Invalid bitcode signature".

Comment: I had to re-read this to realize that no output is good news. Now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `file` utility will report that the file is "LLVM IR bitcode". LLVM/clang's LTO facilities don't produce "fat" object files, it's just IR.