# How to tell a library was compiled using C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-libraries

How can I tell if a certain c++ library was linked using 
c++11 standard?

Comment: I am asking because when building mongodb C++ legacy driver one have to make sure that the existing boost is built using the same C++ standard as mongodb driver - which is C++11

Comment: so, you want to know the compiler version as to what compiler version was the binary built with??

Comment: I am not sure how to get what you want, but there is a way to find the version of the compiler. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387040/how-to-retrieve-the-gcc-version-used-to-compile-a-given-elf-executable). You can create a minimum compiler version required list, and sort of achieve that. But again, if -std=c++11 was used while compiling, is not answered as of now.

Comment: Not the compiler version as in whether it was g++ 4.4 or g++ 4 but rather if the compiling was done with a flag for C++11.

Comment: *"one have to make sure that the existing boost is built using the same C++ standard"* - not necessarily... there's no Standard-mandated break in the ABI, so it just depends on whether the specific versions of compilers you've used - with whatever flags you've specified - have breaks.  If I were you, I'd just try it and see if it works.  I certainly link a mix of objects compiled with and without -std=c++11 - but all with the same compiler version - against boost and have seen no issues.

Comment: How do I know that it works? Is Initializing the library enough or do I need full coverage? Beside there is  a comment in the mongo-cxx-driver wiki that says that boost package on ubuntu is not using C++11 and I think it is wrong and I want to prove to the maintainer that it is wrong so he will fix the wiki because it is misleading developers to use the wrong build flags and spend hours figuring out what is wrong. For me mongo-cxx-driver started working only once I built mongo-cxx-driver with the C++11 flag but that could be incidental. right?

Comment: *"boost package on ubuntu is not using C++11"* - that may be true for some or all versions of Ubuntu, but it probably means the boost libraries use other hackier and/or less efficient methods internally to provide their promised functionality... it shouldn't make a visible difference to a client program, except for some rare boost functionality that simply isn't supported for C++03, and even then I'd expect compilation or linking errors not runtime.  I have no idea about your mongo cxx driver... sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elf binary would by default contain the signature of compiler version used.

Now, with regards to compiler flags used, If `-frecord-gcc-switches` is used at compile time, then, you can find the signature in ELF executable.

```
 g++ -frecord-gcc-switches -std=c++0x trial.cpp
readelf -p .GCC.command.line a.out
```

String dump of section '.GCC.command.line':

```
  [     0]  -imultilib . [     d]  -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu   [    2a]  -D_GNU_SOURCE   [ 38]  trial.cpp   [    42]  -mtune=generic   [    51]  -march=x86-64  [    5f]  -std=c++0x   [    6a]  -frecord-gcc-switches   [    80]   
-fstack-protector
```

Comment: How do I get that string dump please?

Comment: using hexedit on libboost_system.so.1.54.0 I get: ibboost_system.so.1.54.0.GCC_3.0.GLIBC_2.4.GLIBC_2.2.5.GLIBCXX_3.4.CXXABI_1.3
maybe the ABI number could help to figure compatibility between boost and mongo driver.

Comment: readelf -p .GCC.command.line a.out..this should give you string dump

Comment: you could also use strings utility...strings a.out|grep "xyz"

Comment: These yielded no result, I guess the boost package I have, was not compiled using -frecord-gcc-switches.

Comment: you can build boost package i guess, if you have the time for it

Comment: Due the lack of a better answer I assume that this is the best we can get - Selecting this as the accepted answer.