# How to find which compiler was used to compile R

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to figure out the compiler used to compile R?  Something like

```
$ R CMD which_compiler_was_used
GCC
```

Or from inside of R

```
> Sys.compiler()
[1] "GCC"
```

I know R CMD SHLIB somehow does the magic...

Comment: You can probably [find it here](https://github.com/wch/r-source).

Comment: @Kenney - that's the source code, not the compiler.

Comment: You might be able to make use of the technique explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9673793/12711

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
R CMD config CC
```

When I try it I get this:

```
gcc -m64
```

**Note:** Issue the `R CMD config` command without `CC` to find out about other information that it can provide.

Comment: Is it also possible to figure out the version of gcc that was used to build R?