# Is there a way one can find out which ndk version was used to compile android .so share library?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-ndk-r4

Is there a way one can find out which ndk version was used to compile android .so share library ?

Comment: sorta similar on elf's ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387040/how-to-retrieve-the-gcc-version-used-to-compile-a-given-elf-executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some hints, like if the file was compiled in 2010, it could not be NDK r10. Or if it was compiled with gcc 4.9, it must have been above r8 (IIRC, I did not check). You can set the lower limit also if it is 64bit. Or if it is for platform 21.

You are in a much better shape if there is a prebuilt STL library next to your **.so**. This file can be binary compared to the versions packed in each NDK release.

Comment: this are really good hints. I think I can accept this for an answer.