# Estimating compiler (GCC or LLVM-clang) version from a stripped ELF binary

Tags: linux, gcc, clang, elf, decompiler

ELF binaries of Linux distributions are stripped and don't include ".comment" section.
Therefore, I could not get the information which compiler build the ELF binary.
I guess most of them are created by GCC and want to know which GCC version is used.

I know that if the ".comment" section is included in the ELF binary, I can get the compiler information using "readelf" or "objdump".
The method was posted before at the stackoverflow.com

[How to retrieve the GCC version used to compile a given ELF executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387040/how-to-retrieve-the-gcc-version-used-to-compile-a-given-elf-executable)

I guess I can use decompiling tools (e.g., Hex-Rays Decompiler https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/ ) to estimate the compiler version.
I also want to know the compiler name if the binary is not created by GCC. For example LLVM-clang.

Do you know a tool to estimate the compiler name and version which create the ELF binary?
I prefer to use a free tool.

Answer (score 1):

> ELF binaries of Linux distributions are stripped and don't include ".comment" section. Therefore, I could not get the information which compiler build the ELF binary.

Most binaries *also* come with a separate `debuginfo` package, which *does* have `.comment` sections, *and* full source package which allows you to configure and build (almost) identical binary.

Examining either the debuginfo, or the source package is a *much easier* and more reliable way to answer your question, then guessing from the binary will ever be.

> Do you know a tool to estimate the compiler name and version which create the ELF binary?

I doubt such a tool exists: writing such a tool would be a mostly pointless exercise.

Comment: *debuginfo* sounds interesting. I can download debuginfo using *debuginfo-insall* command. However, I can not understand how to use it. Please tell me how to know the compiler version from the *debuginfo*.